# Python Code to store 2 values that are paired together

Tags: python, sorting, arraylist

```
city = ['michigan','toronto;,michigan','denver','michigan','toronto']

for line in lines:
  code <>
  print ("Found ", count_value,"matching ",city)
```

Expected output:
Michigan : 3
Totonto : 2
denver : 1

How do i store count_value to reference or map to city, so i can print the top 3 cities that appeared the most in the list the loop is going though.
I have done the code and can count the number of times a city is found in the list, but how do i print the top 3 highest count of cities in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Counter()` which automatically accumulates the total number of occurrences in your list and sets it to the index values.

```py
from collections import Counter
city = ['michigan', 'toronto', 'michigan', 'denver', 'michigan', 'toronto']
print(Counter(city)) # Outputs -> Counter({'michigan': 3, 'toronto': 2, 'denver': 1})

# To sort by most frequent cities first.
print(Counter(city).most_common()) # ('michigan', 3), ('toronto', 2), ('denver', 1)
```

To get the exact output that you want, you can just iterate over the list and insert the values for each city into a string:

```py
from collections import Counter
city = ['michigan', 'toronto', 'michigan', 'denver', 'michigan', 'toronto']

city = Counter(city).most_common() # Convert city into a Counter of all the city occurrences.

totalCityString = ""
for key in city: totalCityString += key[0] + ": " + str(key[1]) + " "

print(totalCityString) # Outputs -> 'michigan: 3 toronto: 2 denver: 1'
```

Comment: Yes this does the counting pretty well, where im stuck is to print the output as below whereby i can extract the city, then a colun, then the count as below.                        Expected output: Michigan : 3 Totonto : 2 denver : 1

Comment: @Warlock I have updated the answer to include code to match your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

What youre looking for is called a dictionary; Which is really easy in python. You need to create a dictionary with the cities (they might need default values at first) then when you do your finding logic, assign that city the value (here is an untested example):

```
dict = {'michigan','toronto;,michigan','denver','michigan','toronto'}
for line in lines:
  code <>
  dict[city] = count_value
```